# what is fn*, and how does it differ from fn?

Tags: clojure

I looked at the source of `lazy-seq` I found this:

```
Clojure 1.4.0
user=> (source lazy-seq)
(defmacro lazy-seq
 "Takes a body of expressions that returns an ISeq or nil, and yields
  a Seqable object that will invoke the body only the first time seq
  is called, and will cache the result and return it on all subsequent
  seq calls. See also - realized?"
  {:added "1.0"}
  [& body]
  (list 'new 'clojure.lang.LazySeq (list* '^{:once true} fn* [] body)))
nil
user=>
```

I was wondering how `fn*` differs from `fn`, but I can't seem to find any reference to `fn*` in the docs. What am I missing, and how is `fn*` different?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm a long way from a Clojure compiler expert, so take the following with an appropriate quantity of salt.

`fn*` is an *intrinsic* version of `fn`. Much of Clojure is implemented in Clojure, but some of the low-level functions are implemented in Java; `fn*` is one such.

`fn` is implemented in terms of `fn*`. The source is here:

https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L42

`fn*` is implemented in the compiler:

https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java#L47

There are actually two different versions of `fn*`, referred to in the Java by the symbols `FN` and `FNONCE`. The first is a "bare" `fn*` and the second is `fn*` with the metadata `^{:once true}`, which is the version used by `lazy-seq`.

`^{:once true}` is used to let the compiler know that the closure containing the function will only be invoked once, and that it can perform closed-over local clearing. See [this mailing list thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/Ys3kEz5c_eE) for more details.

Comment: This is correct. I'd add that `fn*` is an implementation detail, and not part of the clojure API; that's why it's not included in the docs.